# What's the optimal solution for a candy dispenser that will dispense one candy at a time despite its size?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Non-engineer and terrible googler here, apologies.

I'm building an arduino project that will dispense candy when the time is right to take it. I am having problems with the physical aspect of the gadget, as I don't know how to dispense one candy at a time (given that different medicines have different sizes).

Imagine you have a simple container like this

```
|        |
|        |
|        |
---------
```

and you can fill it with candy (of every different size, but each set of candy is the same size), e.g.

```
|**     |                   |        |
|*******|                   |     @@@|
|*******|                   |@@@@@@@@|
---------                   ----------
(small size candy)      (bigger size candy)
```

Now what could be done so that only ONE container like this can handle one candy falling at a time?
If the candy were always of the same size, this would not have been a problem. However, with different sized candy, this is problematic

Comment: Have you thought of looking at vending machine mechanisms?

Comment: It is never a good idea to have an automatic dispencer of medecines....